# Manage font type and size of text on Matlab plot

Tags: image, matlab, octave

I have achieved to plot a 28x28 grayscale image on Matlab and also to insert a number at a particular location of the figure, but how can I increase the size of the font, change its color or its type (e.g. verdana).

```
% myImage is a 28x28 matrix with values from 0 to 255
imagesc(myImage);
colormap(gray)

%insert text
text(1,1,'7');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup.  Use the `'FontName'` attribute.  If you want to change the size, use `'FontSize'`, and finally for the colour, use the `'Color'` attribute... so something like this:

```
text(1, 1, '7', 'FontName', 'verdana', 'FontSize', 16, 'Color', 'blue');
```

Change the above attributes to whatever you want, but I've made the font size 16, the font Verdana and the colour of the text blue.  More information about the `text` function and its attributes can be found in the official MathWorks documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html

Here's an example of this in action:

```
>> im = rand(7,7);
>> imagesc(im);
>> text(1, 1, '7', 'FontName', 'verdana', 'FontSize', 16, 'Color', 'red');
```

We get this figure:

[image]

You can see that we switched to Verdana, and we placed a blue 7 with font size 16 and location `(1,1)` in the image.

Comment: Duh! I'm getting started with Matlab and didn't think of checking the function itself... thanks for that!

Comment: @Victor - No problem at all :) I've added in a reproducible example so you can see that it works.  BTW, I know I've answered this question quickly... but when you get around to it, I wouldn't mind an accept :) thanks!

Comment: For sure, as soon as I can I'll accept it. Thanks @rayryeng !!